# Equation exceeds one column of IEEE

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, ieeetran

Equation exceeds one column of IEEE pattern in LaTeX how should I correct it? Please help, the code is attached herewith.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq11}
        p\left( {v,h|u,y,...} \right) = {\rm{RelU}}\left( {\left[ {\hat b + {w^h}\left\{ {\left( {{v^T}{w^v}} \right) \circ \left( {{y^T}{w^y}} \right)} \right\}} \\ \right]*\left[ {\hat a + {w^v}\left\{ {\left( {{h^T}{w^h}} \right) \circ \left( {{y^T}{w^y}} \right)} \right\}} \right]} \right)
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Long equations are not automatically split as this requires the author's judgment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line breaks aren't possible in an `equation` environment. There are likely several possible ways of doing this, one is to use `multline` from `amsmath`, another is a `split` environment inside `equation`. Note that `\left`/`\right` cannot span a line break, and that you have a lot of brace pairs that are not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RelU}{RelU}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{multline}\label{eq11}
   p(v,h|u,y,...) = 
   \RelU\bigl( \bigl[ \hat b + w^h \{ ( v^T w^v ) \circ ( y^T w^y ) \}  \bigr]* \\
    \bigl[ \hat a + w^v \{ ( h^T w^h ) \circ ( y^T w^y ) \} \bigr] \bigr)
\end{multline}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}\label{eq12}
\begin{split}
   p(v,h|u,y,...) &= 
   \RelU\bigl( \bigl[ \hat b + w^h \{ ( v^T w^v ) \circ ( y^T w^y ) \}  \bigr]* \\
   &\phantom{{}=\RelU\bigl(} \bigl[ \hat a + w^v \{ ( h^T w^h ) \circ ( y^T w^y ) \} \bigr] \bigr)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using `multline`. I took the opportunity to improve and simplify the code:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{multline}\label{eq11}
        p\bigl(v,h\mid u,y\dots \bigr) = \\
  \mathrm{RelU}\Bigl( \Bigl[ {\hat b + {w^h}\bigl\{\bigl(v^T w^v \bigr) \circ \bigl(y^T w^y \bigr) \bigr\}}\Bigr] \\ *
  \Bigl[ {\hat a + {w^v}\bigl\{ \bigl(h^Tw^h \bigl) \circ \bigl( y^T w^y \bigr) \bigr\}} \Bigr] \Bigr)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `equation` environment with `split` as it automatically ***vertically justifies the equation number*** and is slightly more compact.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={3in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\textbf{this is with multiline package}
\begin{multline}\label{eq11}
        p\bigl(v,h\mid u,y\dots \bigr) = \\
  \mathrm{RelU}\Bigl( \Bigl[ {\hat b + {w^h}\bigl\{\bigl(v^T w^v \bigr) \circ \bigl(y^T w^y \bigr) \bigr\}}\Bigr] \\ *
  \Bigl[ {\hat a + {w^v}\bigl\{ \bigl(h^Tw^h \bigl) \circ \bigl( y^T w^y \bigr) \bigr\}} \Bigr] \Bigr)
\end{multline}


\textbf{this is with equation package}
\begin{equation}\label{eq11}
\begin{split}
        p\bigl(v,h\mid u,y\dots \bigr) = \\
  \mathrm{RelU}\Bigl( \Bigl[ {\hat b + {w^h}\bigl\{\bigl(v^T w^v \bigr) \circ \bigl(y^T w^y \bigr) \bigr\}}\Bigr] \\ *
  \Bigl[ {\hat a + {w^v}\bigl\{ \bigl(h^Tw^h \bigl) \circ \bigl( y^T w^y \bigr) \bigr\}} \Bigr] \Bigr)
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Equation package vertically aligns the equation number]